# Wrong total reputation only in quarter and year user stats

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

In my user stats from Stack Overflow all 'total reputations' are correct, but the [quarter](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow) and [year](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow) count is too high (both are ten too much). They were apparently not corrected with the [large corrections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123319/172024) at the beginning of the month.

It is envisaged that these values ​​can also be corrected or did I miss something?

=== UPDATE ===

Thanks Nick for your answer.

1.) I can't understand why my downvotes are calculated in the 'all time' but e.g. not in the 'year' stats. Where is the difference?

2.) There is no privacy, everybody can calculate the downvotes by comparing following reputation views:

I am not logged in! On the [Users site](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year&search=scessor) I'm searching for my user and click on 'year':

[image: Users]

If I click on the 'Top Users' link (with the green arrow), click on 'year' and search for my user again:

[image: Top Users]

Then you have two different values. The difference are the downvotes? (You can repeat this with each user.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 10 downvotes on answers which cost you 1 rep each.

We don't show these in your profile (unless it's you viewing it), nor do we show them in the leagues, for your voting privacy.  Because of this some aggregate totals may be slightly off compared to the private view of your profile...but will match the public view which excludes downvotes and votes from removed posts.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: @scessor - The total shown on `/users` in includes *everything*, all rep changes...that's intentional at the moment, and for technical reasons will likely remain that way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying here. The score reported in the reputation leagues does *not* include the cost of downvotes? Is that a temporary caching issue, or a permanent feature? It sounds like a bug to me. The fact that you cast 10 downvotes on random questions should not be a privacy issue, and it *does* affect your score, so it should be considered in those totals.

Comment: @Cody - We hide downvotes and votes for deleted posts from the public reputation list in your profile, why would we show days where the totals for the same intervals **didn't** match that in the leagues?

Comment: Your answer is probably correct; I don't like it. But there are more important things in life :-)